# Meaning of "living within means"

Tags: meaning, idioms

> Anyone who **lives within their means** suffers from a lack of imagination.
> — Oscar Wilde.

What does *living within means* mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this context, *means* refers to a person's assets and/or income.  So, to "live within your means" refers to not spending out of proportion with your income.

Comment: Not to be confused with the Ways and Means Committe of Congress, which *always* lives outside its means.

Answer (score 6):

Ask a literary-inspired question, get a literary answer:

> Annual income twenty pounds, annual expenditure nineteen nineteen six, result happiness.
>    Annual income twenty pounds, annual expenditure twenty pound ought and six, result misery.

([Mr Micawber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkins_Micawber#Popular_culture), in [David Copperfield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Copperfield_%28novel%29), by [Charles Dickens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Dickens))